# Ethernet connection suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

I'm using windows 10 professional. I have a router given by mu ISP. It has wifi and 4 Ethernet ports. Wifi is working fine (my phone is connected to it), but Ethernet just stopped working, suddenly.
I tried with a different Ethernet cable no luck. I already had newest drivers installed. I reset the network, and after that did a clean install of windows again, no luck. However, when I go to command prompt, I try to ping google.com and it works.
I really really have no idea what could be the problem.. everything was working fine (for years) until today..

[image]

Comment: Does 'Ethernet' show as connected in control panel? What's your IPv4 DNS address? Does the same PC connect to WiFi ok?

Comment: Yes it shows as connected. Ip4 address is 192.168.0.12. No, other devices such as tablets and phones are using wifi, pc only uses Ethernet

Comment: Can you reboot the router? Did you tried another Ethernet port on the router?

Comment: Tried both of those..

Comment: Is the problem that the Ethernet connection is working, but you don't have Internet connectivity? Can you extract the Ethernet interface configuration using `ipconfig /all` and add it to your question. Make sure that the gateway address is your router, and that you can `ping` it. Type `route` and make sure that the default route (IP 0.0.0.0, mask 0.0.0.0) uses the IP of the Ethernet connection and the gateway of the router and that no other active routes match Internet addresses. Also, make sure that there is nothing barring port 80 access in your firewall or router configuration.

Comment: I can ping the router. I've uploaded the image of the Ethernet interface.

Comment: I came here because I have the same problem. Did you resolve it in the end?